# How to check is spring.datasource.url string valid?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, sql-server-2019

Is there any way to check if spring.datasource.url is correct? I'm not sure, because it doesn't matter what I write, there aren't any errors in console.

I use ms sql server 2019 on localhost with windows credential as authentication

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-3ABC;database=event_db;integratedSecurity=true
```

I have problem with this error and I suppose, it might be because of incorrect connection string

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repository in com.example.controller.CampaignController required a bean of type 'com.example.data.EventTypeRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.data.EventTypeRepository' in your configuration.de here
```

Comment: can you share the CampaignController and EventTypeRepository code? (at least the constructor or @Autowired parts)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to your Datasource configuration. It's a bean configuration issue. Check if you have correctly annotated your classes.

At this point, your Datasource configuration has not been initialized. If you are able to rectify your bean configuration issue, then your Datasource will be initialized and if there's an issue with it, you will be given a proper error message indicating what's wrong with the Datasource.

Example:

- invalid database name -> FATAL: database "invalid_database_name" does not exist
- incorrect or unreachable db host -> The connection attempt failed.